# Group by clause vs. Distinct()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct

My ASP.NET custom list control gets its values from a database `View`. The method which retrieves data finally returns an object of type `List<Triplet>` as a DataSource for the control.

I figured out three possible implementations for that method which all seem to work fine and give the same results. Now I'm not sure which of them should be preferred.

The point is, that I need unique strings from the query in alphabetical order, and there are *many* duplicates in the db. So I could fetch them all and then perfom a Distinct() to get unique values...

```cs
public override object GetData()
{
    return 
    (
        from name in
        (
            from job in DBConnection.NewDataContext.vJobs
            where job.name != null 
            select job.name

        ).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s) 

        select new Triplet(name, name, ListType)

    ).ToList();
 }
```

...or I could use a group by clause and only select the keys:

```cs
public override object GetData()
{
    return 
    (
        from job in DBConnection.NewDataContext.vJobs 
        where job.name != null
        group job by job.name into names 
        orderby names.Key 
        select new Triplet(names.Key, names.Key, ListType)

    ).ToList();
}
```

I also came up with the following, which uses a special `EqualityComparer` for the Triplets. Actually it was my first approach, but I didn't really like it:

```cs
public override object GetData()
{
    return
    (
        from job in DBConnection.NewDataContext.vJobs 
        where job.name != null
        select new Triplet(job.name, job.name, ListType)

    ).ToList().Distinct(new TripletComparer()).OrderBy(t => (string)t.First).ToList();
}
```

I think the goup-by-solution leaves most of the work to the database (MS SQL Server), which might be an advantage or disadvantage.. I don't really know. Maybe the Distict()-solutution suffers from having to push too much unneccessary data from the db to my method?

Any ideas which one should be implemented? It seems I just can't see the forest because of too many trees...

Comment: 1.) This seems like premature optimization 2.) This should probably be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com 3.) Let the SQL Server do the work, that's what it's good at.

Comment: I think fundamentally the `GroupBy` offers functionality to group multiple objects of the same key under one object, which is useful in scenarios like grouping by countries. Distinct will only find one of that key and leave it at that. So you for the countries scenario, you would only get one object for each country

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry for being off-topic here. Never heard of Code Review before, it is not mentioned in the help center. Please have mercy with a newcomer.

Comment: BTW, this question is of the kind "Best way to...?", and there are many such questions on stackoverflow without being considered off-topic. ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until there is a need to concern yourself with performance (that is, [do not micro-optimize](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)) then you should probably opt for the most readable solution which is clearly to call `Distinct` as that conveys your intent very clearly.

If you are truly concerned about the performance, then I suggest you perform some concrete benchmarks using a [profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/l2sprof).

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the links. So I'll use the `Distinct` solution. And yes, maybe it's micro optimization... But the site I'm working on is already slow enough, and of course it is not the only query of this kind in the application. I just don't want to add another bottleneck if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are many duplicates, applying the distinct in the database is the best.

Linq-2-sql use deferred loading. However, calling `ToList()` will have your query executed in the database, so everything after that is in memory.

Therefore the first one is probably the best.