# How could distinct multi array list on c#

Tags: c#, list, distinct

Consider objModels is object of ChildModel class

```
public class ChildModel
{
public string Title { get; set; }
public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

It has some data like:
title,id: **a,1  b,1  a,1**

Two of these data are same, and after distinct it could be like: **a,1  b,1**

Question is how could I distinct it on c#

```
List<ChildModel> obj= objModels.ToList();
```

Also these aren't help

```
objModels.Distinct();
obj.Distinct();
```

Comment: you have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, like [this so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317582/correct-way-to-override-equals-and-gethashcode), [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358.aspx)

Comment: I answered friend dont forget vote up and accept it

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari thank you man, but "DistinctBy" isn't exist when I try to use

Comment: look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Comment: thank you friend  please vote up too :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var answer= obj.DistinctBy(p => new { p.Id , p.Title });
```

and check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) for other way

Comment: `DistinctBy` requires the MoreLINQ library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library named [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

This is the query you could use with MoreLINQ to find elements that are distinct by multiple properties:

```
var query = objModels.DistinctBy(p => new { p.Id, p.Title});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.GroupBy`:

```
var result= obj
  .GroupBy(p => p.Title)
  .Select(g => g.First()) // choose which one
  .ToList();
```

edit: if you want to `GroupBy` more than one `Property` you can just change `p.Title` to `new {p.Title, p.Id}` like so

```
var result= obj
  .GroupBy(p => new {p.Title, p.Id})
  .Select(g => g.First()) // choose which one
  .ToList();
```

Comment: this is so baad way to dothis

Comment: This would only Group items by Title, he needs items to be distinct by both Id and Title.

Comment: Guys this works on this code, I checking, but on c# I haven't "DistinctBy" during a list like this

Comment: @sachin edited my post - was not really clear for me if OP wants more or less properties to be grouped

Comment: @Shahrooz Ansari  why is this a bad way?

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep watch this links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066346/linq-groupby-vs-distinct   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869683/group-by-clause-vs-distinct

Comment: @ShahroozAnsari maybe it is faster .. maybe its not! No measurements of performance there. Seems more like a personal preference to take distinct over groupby (both fullfill the req. of OP).

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
            namespace ConsoleApplication7
            {
                class Program
                {
                    static void Main()
                    {
                        List<ChildModel> list = new List<ChildModel>();
                        list.Add(new ChildModel { Title = "a", Id = 1 });
                        list.Add(new ChildModel { Title = "b", Id = 1 });
                        list.Add(new ChildModel { Title = "a", Id = 1 });

                        var x = list.Distinct(new ChildModelComparer()).ToList();

                        var y = x; //This has only got two child items.

                    }
                }
                class ChildModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<ChildModel>
                {
                    public bool Equals(ChildModel x, ChildModel y)
                    {
                        return x.Id.Equals(y.Id) && x.Title.Equals(y.Title);
                    }

                    public int GetHashCode(ChildModel obj)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Title) && obj.Id == 0)
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        return $"{obj.Id}{obj.Title}".GetHashCode();
                    }
                }
                public class ChildModel
                {
                    public string Title { get; set; }
                    public long Id { get; set; }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have used IEqualityComparer so that I can use the second overload of distinct.